# VS: Attribute for ignoring missing XML comments when building

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, attributes, xml-comments

I have a VS2008 solution using xml documentation, and we have warnings as errors turned on for release mode (a nice feature IMHO); this results, however, in long lists of 'missing xml comment' errors for such things as every element of a (self describing) enum.

Does anyone know of an attribute or similar which switches off the requrement for xml comments? Ideally for some delimited area, not just one line (otherwise I could just put empty tags before every item, kind of defeating the purpose...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use #pragma warning disable.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(VS.80).aspx